# Does anybody know about Chemipro Acid?

Tags: sanitation, sanitizer, starsan

I'm living in the Netherlands and it seems that Starsan isn't available here.  I'm wondering if anyone knows if Chemipro Acid is the same thing?  Or just what's in it?

For reference, see here:

http://www.brouwland.com/shop/product.asp?cfid=4&id=1821&cat=530&dt=24

and here:

http://www.brouwland.com/content/assets/home/reinigenENG.htm

They don't seem to say, so just wondering if anyone can shed any light on the matter.

Thanks a lot,

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't speak with any authority, but it appears to be *similar* but not identical.  The color of the product appears more amber/brown, and the disclaimer that it needs to be drained well doesn't seem to be quite the same as StarSan's motto of "don't fear the foam".  However, they are both acid-based sanitizers and likely work in a similar method.

If it's available to you then it's worth trying, but I would not consider it an equivalent to StarSan(by which I mean it may not be better or wose, just different)--be careful to read the directions and labels and to use it as it's manufacturer describes; don't try to follow StarSan's directions unless you're using StarSan.

I wouldn't be concerned that this isn't a brand-name sanitizer; it's likely that it will work as well as StarSan.

Comment: Thanks, however I guess the difficulty is the wording:

"Belgian and Dutch legislation prevents us from describing a product as having a disinfectant action without having it registered as a pesticide. For small companies this is a wearisome and exorbitantly expensive process. Hence you will not find ‘disinfectant’ on any single piece of packaging."

It leads me to wonder what actually is a sanitiser, and what is a cleaner - they sell a percarbonate in the same range, which is really a cleaner.